# set nested element symbol

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Given a nested set $S = \{\{e_{11},e_{12},\dots,e_{1n}\},\{e_{21},e_{22},\dots,e_{2n}\},\dots,\{e_{k1},e_{k2},\dots,e_{kn}\}\}$, I want to specify a set consisting of specific subelements, for example $X = \{e_{12},e_{22},\dots,e_{k2}\}$. Therefore, it seems that a symbol for nested element would be helpful. For example:

$X = \{e_{i1}|e_{i1}\in\in S\}$ or $X = \{e_{i1}|e_{i1}\in^* S\}$

For single nesting I might use $X = \{e_{i1}|e_{i1}\in S'\in S\}$ or $X = \{e_{i1}|e_{i1} \in \bigcup S\}$ (which both do not look very nice), but what about nesting with an arbitrary number of levels?

Comment: Many years ago, I thought of the notion of level of such a "level $k$ element" of a set $S$. I wrote something as $x\in_{k}S$ defined as $x\in S$ iff $x\in_{1} S$ and $x\in_{k+1}S$ iff there is a sequence $(S_{i})_{1\le i\le k}$ such that $S_{i+1}\in S_{i}$, with $S_{1}=S$ and $x\in S_{k+1}$.

Comment: I got mixed up with the number of levels (it's getting late and my brain is sleepy) but I guess you got the idea.